# Should C macros that are specific to function be defined and un-defined in the function's scope?

Tags: c, macros

I would like to know if there is another reason besides style preference to define and un-define macros specific to a function within a C function's scope.

For example:

```
static float pay(float hours)
{
    #define REG_PAY_HOURS 40.0
    #define REG_PAY_RATE  15.0
    #define OT_PAY_RATE   (1.5 * PAY_RATE)

    if(REG_PAY_HOURS >= hours)
    {
        return(hours * REG_PAY_RATE);
    }
    else
    {
        return((REG_PAY_HOURS * REG_PAY_RATE) + ((hours - REG_PAY_HOURS) * OT_PAY_RATE));
    }

    #undef OT_PAY_RATE
    #undef REG_PAY_RATE
    #undef REG_PAY_HOURS
}
```

vs.

```
#define REG_PAY_HOURS 40.0
#define REG_PAY_RATE  15.0
#define OT_PAY_RATE   (1.5 * PAY_RATE)
static float pay(float hours)
{
    if(REG_PAY_HOURS >= hours)
    {
        return(hours * REG_PAY_RATE);
    }
    else
    {
        return((REG_PAY_HOURS * REG_PAY_RATE) + ((hours - REG_PAY_HOURS) * OT_PAY_RATE));
    }
}
#undef OT_PAY_RATE
#undef REG_PAY_RATE
#undef REG_PAY_HOURS
```

Thanks

Comment: preprocessor has no scope. It's the same thing.

Comment: some coding standards, e.g. google coding standard, recommend doing this to avoid collision. i think it depends on usage: if you want those macros to be configurable parameters then it's more convenient to move them to the top of the file.

Comment: Should the references to `PAY_RATE` actually be `REG_PAY_RATE`?

Comment: So this question is inside v. just outside of?

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no reason except stylistic choice.

The preprocessor is not aware of the function, it doesn't parse C at that level.

I'd say that `#undef`:ing macros is kind of rare, but it can of course be a good idea to make it clearer that the macros are meant to be local.

Answer (score 1):

For your use case it would be preferable to use constants instead of macros, i.e.,

```
const float REG_PAY_HOURS = 40.0f;
const float REG_PAY_RATE  = 15.0f;
const float OT_PAY_RATE   = 1.5f * PAY_RATE;
```

Advantages are better type-safety and less danger of forgetting braces. Any reasonable compiler should be able to optimize these values as good (or better) as macro-constants. Also, if you declare your constants inside a function, that is exactly where they can be accessed, and there is no need to `#undef` them afterwards.